# COBOL -> COBOL/DB2 -> COBOL -> COBOL/DB2 pgm call

Tags: db2, bind, cobol

Lets say like PGM1(cobol) calls--> PGM2(cobol-db2) calls--> PGM3(cobol)--> calls PGM4(cobol-db2). 
1Q. PGM3 is modified, which is purely COBOL progam. Do we compile only PGM3 and promote it to production or should we do a BIND again as its being called by and calls cobol-db2 program.
2Q. If PGM4 is modifieed, then what has to be done. (I'm using PACKAGE -> PLAN concept) ?
Also, can any one please explain me bind with package concept when we have cobol-cobol/db2 call.

Comment: You should edit your question and explain what objects are being `BIND`ed together.  The way your question is written (programs calling programs), `BIND`'s don't matter at all.

Comment: Hi Benny. Thanks for your comment. This is one of the question's faced in interview. There we cannot expect every thing as clear given in requirement doc. If some overview is given for such concept/requirement, it will help learners a lot.

Comment: Static or dynamic? SQL changing or not? Software available (like a "bind manager"? Etc? The answer when asked in an interview is "no way to tell without more information, but..." and then give the really basic answers, which can all be found through research, where you'll more easily remember it, rather than have someone read the manuals for you.

Comment: StackOverflow does not exist to help people answer interview questions - questions that are often intentionally ambiguous in order to see how knowledgeable a candidate is about the topic at hand. If someone wants to do well in an interview, they should spend their time **learning the subject** rather than trying to memorize answers given to them by Internet users.

Comment: @ASHOKPOLURU Also, it's not clear what COBOL compiler is used. What platform is it on? How is the COBOL run unit defined? Any answers may be very different between ILE COBOL on IBM i and other compilers on z OS (or elsewhere). As for answering interview questions, that does a disservice to employers giving interviews and damages any relationship with SO.

Answer (score 5):

Ashok,

Its definitely a question of how you making calls.A call can be static and dynamic.
With Dynamic call you do not need to compile main program is sub program changes.
But with Static call you need to compile Main program too.

Ans1 :- Static call in all calls  - yes you must compile all programs.
        Dynamic call used - just compile sub program.

Ans 2 :- See full details below for package and plan concept.

If you bound the old versions of  DBRMs directly into your plan,

· Identify all the DBRMs that are bound directly into that plan for both the changed programs and any unchanged programs, and bind them all into the plan again.

·While you are binding the DBRMs into the plan, applications cannot use the plan to access DB2.

If you bound the old versions of the DBRMs for the changed application programs into packages

·You do not need to bind any other packages or directly-bound DBRMs into the plan again.

·You simply bind the new versions of the DBRMs for the changed application programs into packages with the same names as the old versions.

·You do not need to bind the plan again--it locates the new versions of the packages.

·While you are changing the packages, application programs can still use the other packages and directly-bound DBRMs in the plan.

Hope this helps!!.

Comment: Unless your source-control system insists, and unless you don't catalog objects, you only *ever* need to compile programs where something has changed *within that program*. For static calls you then run the linkeditor/binder which will pick up the new objects. So, no, without know what is set up for a particular site, it is extremely difficult, long-winded and largely pointless to try to answer such questions. Similar with the DB2 side. Without knowing site procedures and software available, you can't give a specific answer and a general answer comes so full of caveats as to not be useful.

Comment: I agree with you Bill without full knowledge of as how your shop is set up we can never be sure.
 these setups  are complex and need involvement of  system programmers too.
We should  follow shop standards documents.
But at the same time ,at general level how things should work without much deep diving in internal setup, will always be helpful.

Especially when we are not given any additional details.

Comment: Not literally true, even if source has not changed, copyfiles and LE updates or compiler support withdrawal may necessitate a recompile. For instance Single Pass may only be officially supported. 

But yes, link edit (like a windows program incremental link) can stitch together old and new. Mr Spolsky would have us recompile everything just to be sure it still will.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, if the "consistency token" changes, you should rebind. That is say, if a new DBRM is produced. Draw a picture. It will help. Linking is really a red herring here. If you don't know what a consistency token is you will after your -805. Ask a peer for help (in the first instance).

Also ask you peers about impact analysis. (What else am I not recompiling that I should ?).

Answer (score 1):

If the subroutine contains static SQL statements then it will produce a DBRM when compiled. This changes the consistency token and thus requires the module to be rebound to the database to avoid an 818 consistency token error. If the subroutine contains no SQL then it does not ever need to be bound to the database because no DBRM is ever created for it.

Even a program that contains only dynamic SQL will still create a DBRM that must be bound to the database. The DBRM itself will be pretty much empty apart from the consistency token.

This holds true regardless of whether this is mainframe COBOL or distributed COBOL using DB2 or LUW.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I had to write any COBOL but we always had two relevant rule of thumbs.

1. Only use Static Calls - your code should be performance tested and if there is no need for a dynamic call for a very specific purpose avoid it at all costs.
2. Rebind everything when something is changed and check the access paths created PRIOR to putting it live

If you need to wait for a period of outage to complete the task and flip in the updated code in production I would be patient and plan one in and complete the bind then...or get a DBA to do it and get them to confirm it was successful in your outage window or roll back immediately.

If your development environment is sufficiently sophisticated complete the bind in a lower pre-production environment using the stats for the DB2 tables from production (Copy the data in if you can - or get a DBA to do it). And check that none of the access paths for any of the DB2 calls have changed.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
First use this DB2 SQL to get the CONTOKENs

SELECT SUBSTR(COLLID,1,12) AS COLLID ,
       SUBSTR(NAME,1,8) AS NAME ,
       HEX(CONTOKEN) AS CONTOKEN ,
       SUBSTR(OWNER,1,8) AS OWNER ,
       SUBSTR(CREATOR,1,8) AS CREATOR ,
       PDSNAME ,BINDTIME 
       FROM SYSIBM.SYSPACKAGE 
       WHERE NAME= 'program name';
 
Get the DB2 CONTOKEN  (example below)
1ADB70E30768F694
0768F6941ADB70E3  (then reversed contoken 4bytes+4bytes)

Check #1 use reversed token search
Use token 0768F6941ADB70E3  (reversed)
         CONTROL.???????.CICSLIB
    Should be found

Check #2 use non-reversed token into DBRMLIB
CONTROL.????????.CIC.DBRMLIB           
-Use token 1ADB70E30768F694
Should be found
```

If found then your bind is good.